# Tips on literature for solving this kind of optimization problems.

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am attempting to write an optimization algorithm for solving a problem of the following nature:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $i \in (1,2,..., K)$
$$\min f(x) \text{ subject to }$$
$$g_i(x)  \le 0, i = 1, 2, ..C$$
$$\text{and } a_k \le x_k \le b_k, 1\le k \le n$$

where $f$ is bounded and non-decreasing and $g_i$ are bounded non-increasing functions, i.e. $f(x + dx e_i) \ge f(x)$ and $g_i(x + dx e_i) \le g_i(x)$ for all $dx \ge 0$ and all standard basis vectors $e_i$. That is all that is known, so we can't assume continuity, linearity nor convexity.

I'm kinda new in the optimization field so I would like to get some tips on literature that can get me starting solving such problems as described above. In my case, $f$ is an expensive function (not the $g_i 's$), so an approach taking into account expensive functions calls would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why write your own optimization algorithm? Unless there is a reason not to, use an off the shelf constrained nonlinear nonconvex optimization solver.

Comment: @JustANoob: can you give more details about where this problem comes from?

Comment: @cvanaret It's related to water modelling in cities. $x$ encodes certain actions to be done, $f$ the cost of implementation and the constraints encode some minimal performance measures that are required.  I have been using evolutionary algorithms to solve this problem but would like to try other methods. I assume that knowing that the $f$ is non-decreasing and $g_i$'s non-increasing should simplify the search for the minima.

Comment: Without continuity or differentiability, hardly ;) Are $f$ and $g_i$ computed by a simulation?

Comment: @cvanaret Yes, its simulation runs. What if we assume continuity and differentiability?  Do you have any tips on theory regarding this specific optimization type of problem? Can't find any.

Comment: As is, this is a classical nonlinear optimization problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming). Just use any state-of-the-art solver to solve it. What programming language are you working with?